# Build multiple jsonnet files at once

Tags: jsonnet

The current jsonnet compiler only allows compile one file at a time. Is there any way to build many jsonnet files in one command, maybe with a rule like all jsonnet files matching pattern *.jsonnet in folder recursively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question: no, the `jsonnet` CLI only accepts a single jsonnet file, note that this is by design, to be able to output (i.e. *manifest*) a *valid* JSON stream.
Recall that JSON itself doesn't have a multi-doc "feature" like YAML has (i.e. `---\n` separated chunks).

That said, depending on your use case, you may be able to use the `-m <dir>` CLI feature, which creates a file per (main) *object* *key*, for example:

```
$ cat multi.jsonnet
{
  'out1.json': { foo: 'bar' },
  'out2.json': { qqq: 'baz' },
}

$ jsonnet multi.jsonnet
{
   "out1.json": {
      "foo": "bar"
   },
   "out2.json": {
      "qqq": "baz"
   }
}

$ jsonnet -m . multi.jsonnet
./out1.json
./out2.json
```

Then, it would be matter of setting these "main" object keys to the per-file manifested content you'd need.

Comment: Ah, yes seems like the only way is to import all jsonnet files into a main file and compile it